# firestore onSnapshot executing twice

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore onSnapshot() function is being called twice.

```
let user = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userID).onSnapshot
({                    
    next: (documentSnapshot: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) =>
    {
         this.userArray.push(documentSnapshot as User);
         console.log(documentSnapshot);
         //here
    },
    error: (firestoreError: firebase.firestore.FirestoreError) =>
    {
         console.log(firestoreError);
         //here
    }
});
```

I have also tried subscribing like in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener by including user() at the //here comment but to no avail.

How can I modify such that the function only executes one time, i.e. push only one user object per time instead of twice.

Answer (score 28):

I don't know if this is related to your question. If one is using

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

to give a document a timestamp, then onSnaphot will fire twice. This seem to be because when you add a new document to your database onSnapshot will fire, but the serverTimestamp has not run yet. After a few milliseconds serverTimestamp will run and update you document => onSnapshot will fire again.

I would like to add a small delay before onSnapshot fires (say 0,5s or so), but I couldn't find the way to do this.

You can also make a server side function for onCreate event, I believe that would solve your problem. Maybe your userArray.push-action would be more suitable to execute in server side.

---

**Update:** To learn more about the behavior of `serverTimestamp()` and why it triggers the listener twice read this article: [The secrets of Firestore’s FieldValue.serverTimestamp() — REVEALED!](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b). Also, the official documentation states:

> *When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new data **before the data is sent to the backend**.*

In the article there are a couple of suggested solutions, one of which is to use the `metadata` property of the `snapshot` to find whether the Boolean value of `metadata.hasPendingWrites` is true (which tells you that  the snapshot you’re looking at hasn’t been written to the server yet) or false.

For example, in your case you can check whether `hasPendingWrites` is false and then push the object:

```js
if ( !documentSnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites ){
  // This code will only execute once the data has been written to the server 
  this.userArray.push(documentSnapshot as User);
  console.log(documentSnapshot);
}
```

In a more generic example, the code will look like this:

```js
firestore.collection("MyCollection")
.onSnapshot( snapshot => {

    if ( snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites ){
        // Local changes have not yet been written to the backend
    } else {
        // Changes have been written to the backend
    }

});
```

Another useful approach, found in the documentation is the following:

> *If you just want to know when your write has completed, you can listen to the completion callback rather than using `hasPendingWrites`. In JavaScript, use the Promise returned from your write operation by attaching a .then() callback.*

I hope these resources and the various approaches will help anyone trying to figure out a solution.

**REFERENCES:**

- [Events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes)
- [The hasPendingWrites metadata property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#haspendingwrites)
- [Snapshot Listen Options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.SnapshotListenOptions#includemetadatachanges)

Comment: In my case, when setting `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` from the client, the first notification contained a null value for the relevant field; the second notification contained the server timestamp value.  I wound up using a cloud function to do the same logic and it resolved the double-firing issue for me.

Comment: in my case it was a `new Date()` usage which prob. trigger `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` call internally

Comment: Same thing here.

Comment: the value of metadata.fromCache changing can also trigger an update

Answer (score 1):

If you need a one time response, use the .get() method for a promise.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userID).get().then(snap => {
  this.userArray = [...this.userArray, snap.doc);
});
```

However, I suggest using [AngularFire](http://github.com/angular/angularfire2) (totally biased since I maintain the library). It makes handling common Angular + Firebase tasks much easier.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using `onSnapshot`? As I understand, `get()` will not listen for changes.