# Why addSnapshotListener is called twice on firestore CollectionReference?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use the following code to add a comment to the firestore database:

```
String currentTime = GetTimeStampFunction()
Comment mComment = new Comment(comment, currentUser.getUid(), null, currentTime);
    firebaseFirestore
        .collection(POSTS)
        .document(postId)
        .collection(COMMENTS)
        .add(mComment);
```

Also, I have written a snapshotListener to update the recyclerview whenever a comment is added to the firestore:

```
private CollectionReference commentsReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     ........
     commentsReference = firebaseFirestore
            .collection(POSTS)
            .document(postId)
            .collection(COMMENTS);
     ........
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    commentsReference
        .addSnapshotListener((Activity) context, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e)
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty())
                {
                    comments = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots)
                    {
                        Comment comment = snapshot.toObject(Comment.class).withId(snapshot.getId());
                        comments.add(comment);
                    }

                    CommentsListAdapter adapter = new CommentsListAdapter(context, comments);
                    commentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    System.out.println("List Updated");        }
            }
        });
}
```

So ,the problem is whenever I add a comment, this addSnapshotListener is called twice ("List Updated" is printed twice). I am using the exact code given in [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) . So, why it is happening like this?

**EDIT:**
I just found out that the no. of calls is not twice. its one more than the no. of documents in the collection, ie, if the no. of documents is 3, snapshotlistener is called 4 times.

Comment: not the answer to your question, but you should probably not be making a new adapter every time, just keep a global reference and clear/add items to it

Comment: try move `addSnapshotListener` to `onCreated`, then check if it call twice or not?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh no.. its not working.. still calling two times.

Comment: I have edited my question. I just found out that the no. of calls is not twice. its one more than the no. of documents in the collection, ie, if the no. of documents is 3, snapshotlistener is called 4 times.

Comment: You really need to get data in realtime or you can simply use a `get()` call? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I solved the problem. My model  class 'Comment'  had a servertimestamp variable. So, after reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434127/2923116, i removed the timestamp variable and the problem is resolved.

Comment: Good to hear that ;)